# Why childs inside Columns class display in single line?

Tags: css, bulma

I'm developing a web using [Bulma](http://bulma.io) framework .

When i put `column` classed tag inside `columns` , all of child tags displayed in one raw and overflowed from page !

I want break raw when arrived end of  `columns` tag .

What's my wrong ?

This is my code :

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="columns is-parent">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) {?>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth is-child">
      <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <figure class="image is-4by3"> <img src="" alt="Image"> </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="card-title has-text-link"><?php echo $post->title; ?></div>
                <small><?php echo strip_tags(word_limiter($post->content,50)); ?></small>
                <a>#css</a>
                <a>#responsive</a>
                <br> <small>11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be some mismatched or extra tags... Was it a typo or?

Comment: Can you provide more context of the code you posted? From the screenshot it is obvious that there is some additional nesting going on.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman No i tested . i dont have any extra or mismatched Tag

Comment: @tomcek112 everything about code is added . other codes not related to it

Comment: @samnikzad With the above code, there is an extra div. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman oh yes . i will edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added only `is-multiline` to parent tag :

```
<div class="columns is-parent is-multiline" >
```

Problem Solved